# Opening port 22, is there risks?

Tags: ssh

I have a question for you, my situation is this:

I have an ip cam that have an HTTP Panel through which I can watch live recording of the camera. I need to watch my io camera also from remote, but i don’t want to open 80 port on router, for known security reasons. I want to connect through an SSH tunnel. Now I have two question:

1- To create SSH tunnel is necessary to open port 22 on router in which is connected the camera? If yes, is there risks by opening port 22? Can hackers exploit?

2- For example HTTP Basic Auth is easily by passable, is the same also for SSH Login, or this isn’t bypassable if you don’t know user and password?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here, as are questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices. You could try to ask this question on [su]. Also, for security, you can ask on [security.se].

Answer (score 1):

The strength of the ssh login depends on what you have behind, as an ssh server.

Even if it's undoubtedly stronger than a basic auth (literally anything is stronger than that :D), I advise you to avoid exposing port 22, or any other default port, on the internet.

The least you could do to securitize it a bit is using a different, high-value port for your ssh server so that it won't end up in random portscans.

You could also use a VPN server to get into your network from outside.

Comment: Thanks, I thought also to use a VPN, but I don’t found guide to setup it for this situation, can you know some guides?

Comment: what hardware do you use? (maybe router?)
Is that your home network?

Comment: In this network I only have the ip camera and the router provided from my ISP. This haven’t integrated VPN function.

Comment: "_I thought also to use a VPN, but I don’t found guide to setup it for this situation, can you know some guides?_" @FilippoPino, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

> To create SSH tunnel is necessary to open port 22 on router in which is connected the camera?

You "open a port" from WAN inbound. You don't need to open ports on the internal network usually. If you use SSH tunneling to the router as VPN, the camera is not involved in that.

> If yes, is there risks by opening port 22? Can hackers exploit?

You should only ever open a port to a service that you can 100% rely on for handling and repelling Internet attacks. These attacks *will* happen.

If your router is business-grade and runs current software you should be safe using that. Don't forget to keep the router firmware up to date. Opening a direct port to your camera is greatly discouraged as these cameras are not likely "Internet-rated".

Also, use public/private-key authentication or a good (long) password, preferrably randomly generated, not used anywhere else.